# S3 Incremental Backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

I am currently using S3 to store large quantities of account level data such as images, text files and other forms of durable content that users upload in my application. I am looking to take an incremental snapshot of this data (once per week) and ship it off to another S3 bucket. I'd like to do this in order to protect against accidentally data loss, i.e. one of our engineers accidentally deleting a chunk of data in the S3 browser.

Can anyone suggest some methodology for achieving this? Would we need to host our own backup application on an EC2 instance? Is there an application that will handle this out of the box? The data can go into S3 Glacier and doesn't need to be readily accessible, it's more of an insurance policy than anything else.

**EDIT 1**

I believe switching on versioning maybe the answer (continuing to research this):
http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Versioning.html

**EDIT 2**

For others looking for answers to this question, there a good thread on ServerFault. I only came across this later:

https://serverfault.com/questions/9171/aws-s3-bucket-backups

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enabling *versioning* on your bucket is the right solution. It can be used to protect both against accidental deletes and overwrites as well.

There's a question on the S3 FAQ, under "Data Protection", that discusses exactly this issue (accidental deletes/overwrites): http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/#Why_should_I_use_Versioning

Comment: AFAIK versioning doesn't protect against bucket deletion. Some of these 3rd party blob browsers make it trivial to delete a whole bucket with a couple of clicks.

Comment: You can't delete a bucket unless it's empty. If you delete objects in a versioned buckets using "regular" (ie, non-versioned) DELETE Object calls, then the objects are not *really* deleted, only a "deletion marker" is added to the top of the version stack for that object. So you can't delete that bucket. In that sense, versioning prevents against _accidental_ deletion.

If you explicitly want to delete the bucket, you'd be able to -- just run a LIST operation that returns all the versions of all objects, then delete all objects.

Comment: In addition to versioning to protect against accidental deletion of files, if you want to avoid problems with the bucket itself, then replicate the bucket to somewhere else (optionally with IAM permissions that prevent users who can delete the primary bucket from being able to delete the replica).